# Javascript: Extract correct json from php script using id

Tags: javascript, php, json

The issue i am having is i am unable to figure out the correct code through which to extract the information i am looking for

Here firstly is the exhibitions.php

```
<?php
    $exhibitionsarray = array(
            array("exhibition_id" => "1", "exhibition_title" => "New York, New York", "exhibition_subject" => "New York", "ticket_price" => "10",
                "exhibits" => array(
                    array("exhibit_id" => "3", "exhibit_title" => "Brooklyn Bridge from City Hall Park", "exhibit_description" => "New York, June 2005", "exhibit_image" => "brooklynbridge.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "6", "exhibit_title" => "Central Park, New York", "exhibit_description" => "New York, June 2005", "exhibit_image" => "centralpark.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "7", "exhibit_title" => "Chrysler Building at night, New York", "exhibit_description" => "New York, July 2001", "exhibit_image" => "chrysler_building.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG")
                ),
                "locations" => array(
                    array("location_id" => "1", "location_name" => "Kelvingrove Art Gallery and Museum", "location_postcode" => "G3 8AG"),
                    array("location_id" => "3", "location_name" => "Walker Art Gallery", "location_postcode" => "L3 8EL"),
                    array("location_id" => "5", "location_name" => "Tate Modern", "location_postcode" => "SE1 9TG")
                )
            ),
            array("exhibition_id" => "2", "exhibition_title" => "Spanish Cities", "exhibition_subject" => "Spain", "ticket_price" => "15",
                "exhibits" => array(
                    array("exhibit_id" => "9", "exhibit_title" => "Eiffel Bridge, Girona", "exhibit_description" => "Girona, March 2008", "exhibit_image" => "eiffel_bridge.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "13", "exhibit_title" => "Plaza Mayor, Madrid", "exhibit_description" => "Madrid, June 2010", "exhibit_image" => "plazamayor.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "14", "exhibit_title" => "Puppy (Day)", "exhibit_description" => "Bilbao, September 2006 - Puppy in daylight", "exhibit_image" => "puppy_day.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "15", "exhibit_title" => "Puppy (Night)", "exhibit_description" => "Bilbao, March 2011 - Puppy at night", "exhibit_image" => "puppy_night.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK")                                                                      
                ),
                "locations" => array(
                    array("location_id" => "2", "location_name" => "Scottish National Gallery", "location_postcode" => "EH2 2EL")
                )                                               
            ),
            array("exhibition_id" => "3", "exhibition_title" => "A Glasgow Viewpoint", "exhibition_subject" => "Glasgow", "ticket_price" => "5",
                "exhibits" => array(
                    array("exhibit_id" => "2", "exhibit_title" => "Bothwell Castle", "exhibit_description" => "Bothwell, April 2011", "exhibit_image" => "bothwell_castle.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "10", "exhibit_title" => "Hampden Park", "exhibit_description" => "Glasgow, June 2007 - SQA Event", "exhibit_image" => "hampden.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "11", "exhibit_title" => "Hogganfield Loch, Glasgow, Winter", "exhibit_description" => "Glasgow, January 2010", "exhibit_image" => "hogganfield_loch.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "16", "exhibit_title" => "Ramblas", "exhibit_description" => "Barcelona, July 1999 - Ramblas (Two Old Friends from Glasgow)", "exhibit_image" => "ramblas.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "17", "exhibit_title" => "River Clyde at Bothwell", "exhibit_description" => "Bothwell, April 2011 - River Clyde from Bothwell", "exhibit_image" => "river_clyde.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "18", "exhibit_title" => "River Kelvin", "exhibit_description" => "Glasgow, July 2011", "exhibit_image" => "river_kelvin.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "21", "exhibit_title" => "University Avenue", "exhibit_description" => "Glasgow, July 2011", "exhibit_image" => "university_avenue.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK")                                                                     
                ),
                "locations" => array(
                    array("location_id" => "1", "location_name" => "Kelvingrove Art Gallery and Museum", "location_postcode" => "G3 8AG"),
                    array("location_id" => "2", "location_name" => "Scottish National Gallery", "location_postcode" => "EH2 2EL"),
                    array("location_id" => "3", "location_name" => "Walker Art Gallery", "location_postcode" => "L3 8EL"),
                    array("location_id" => "4", "location_name" => "The Lowry", "location_postcode" => "M50 3AZ"),
                    array("location_id" => "5", "location_name" => "Tate Modern", "location_postcode" => "SE1 9TG")
                )                                                   
            ),
            array("exhibition_id" => "4", "exhibition_title" => "Some Churches", "exhibition_subject" => "Religious Architecture", "ticket_price" => "5",
                "exhibits" => array(
                    array("exhibit_id" => "1", "exhibit_title" => "Big Ben", "exhibit_description" => "London, September 2011", "exhibit_image" => "big_ben.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "12", "exhibit_title" => "Louvre, Paris", "exhibit_description" => "Paris, June 1998", "exhibit_image" => "louvre.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "19", "exhibit_title" => "Sagrada Familia - Honeymoon", "exhibit_description" => "Barcelona, June 1997 - Honeymoon", "exhibit_image" => "sagrada.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "20", "exhibit_title" => "Mormon Temple", "exhibit_description" => "Salt Lake City, July 2005", "exhibit_image" => "salt_lake.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG")                                                                      
                ),
                "locations" => array(
                    array("location_id" => "1", "location_name" => "Kelvingrove Art Gallery and Museum", "location_postcode" => "G3 8AG"),
                    array("location_id" => "2", "location_name" => "Scottish National Gallery", "location_postcode" => "EH2 2EL")
                )                                                   
            ),
            array("exhibition_id" => "5", "exhibition_title" => "Barcelona Highlights", "exhibition_subject" => "Barcelona", "ticket_price" => "15",
                "exhibits" => array(
                    array("exhibit_id" => "4", "exhibit_title" => "Martin at Camp Nou, Honeymoon", "exhibit_description" => "Barcelona, June 1997 - Honeymoon", "exhibit_image" => "campnou.jpg", "photographer" => "LPK"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "5", "exhibit_title" => "Placa de Catalunya, Barcelona - Honeymoon", "exhibit_description" => "Barcelona, June 1997 - Honeymoon", "exhibit_image" => "catalunya.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG")
                ),
                "locations" => array(
                    array("location_id" => "3", "location_name" => "Walker Art Gallery", "location_postcode" => "L3 8EL"),
                    array("location_id" => "4", "location_name" => "The Lowry", "location_postcode" => "M50 3AZ"),
                    array("location_id" => "5", "location_name" => "Tate Modern", "location_postcode" => "SE1 9TG")
                )                                                   
            ),
            array("exhibition_id" => "6", "exhibition_title" => "Martin’s Pictures", "exhibition_subject" => "Martin", "ticket_price" => "5",
                "exhibits" => array(
                    array("exhibit_id" => "8", "exhibit_title" => "David Crosby at David Gilmour gig", "exhibit_description" => "Glasgow, May 2006", "exhibit_image" => "davidcrosby.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "22", "exhibit_title" => "Wolves", "exhibit_description" => "Yellowstone Park, October 2004", "exhibit_image" => "wolves.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG")
                ),
                "locations" => array(
                    array("location_id" => "1", "location_name" => "Kelvingrove Art Gallery and Museum", "location_postcode" => "G3 8AG"),
                    array("location_id" => "3", "location_name" => "Walker Art Gallery", "location_postcode" => "L3 8EL"),
                    array("location_id" => "4", "location_name" => "The Lowry", "location_postcode" => "M50 3AZ"),
                    array("location_id" => "5", "location_name" => "Tate Modern", "location_postcode" => "SE1 9TG")
                )
            )               
    );
    echo json_encode($exhibitionsarray);
?>
```

The information i wish depends on the specific exhibition id... and only use exhibits not location so for example when the id = 1  i wish this information...

```
array("exhibition_id" => "1", "exhibition_title" => "New York, New York", "exhibition_subject" => "New York", "ticket_price" => "10",
                "exhibits" => array(
                    array("exhibit_id" => "3", "exhibit_title" => "Brooklyn Bridge from City Hall Park", "exhibit_description" => "New York, June 2005", "exhibit_image" => "brooklynbridge.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "6", "exhibit_title" => "Central Park, New York", "exhibit_description" => "New York, June 2005", "exhibit_image" => "centralpark.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG"),
                    array("exhibit_id" => "7", "exhibit_title" => "Chrysler Building at night, New York", "exhibit_description" => "New York, July 2001", "exhibit_image" => "chrysler_building.jpg", "photographer" => "MLG")
                ),
```

Now here is the code i currently have to get all exhibit info

```
function getExibitions()
{
    console.log(json);
myExhibitionsView = document.getElementById('exhibitioncontent');
images = document.createElement('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < json[i].exhibits.length; j++) {
        listCheck = document.createElement('p');
        listCheck.id = 'image';
        listCheck.innerHTML = "<img src = " + "./images/" + json[i].exhibits[j].exhibit_image + " Photo Cover' height='200' width='200'>";
        console.log(listCheck);
        myExhibitionsView.appendChild(images);
        images.appendChild(listCheck);
        console.log(listCheck);
    }
}

}
```

This code allows me to extract the json and then use the image urls... this is what i wish to do here as well but only if its of the specific id. Thank you very much for the assistance

Comment: I would be easier if you could use the `exhibition_id` as the keys for the `exhibition` arrays. Now you will have to search. So if that an option, I would change that.

Comment: this is the php script i was given... could you explain what u mean @jeroen

Comment: how would i find this information with this php script?

Comment: `$exhibitionsarray = array(1 => array("exhibition_id" => "1", ...`

Comment: brilliant now how would i do this using the code i have added? im not great at using php thanks

Comment: @jeroen could you add an answer to this question using the code im using please? this would not only help me but also others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data in PHP use:

```
foreach( $exhibitionsarray as $val ) {
    if( $val['exhibition_id'] == 1 ) {
        echo "That's the right one, do something now.";
    }
}
```

In Javascript use:

```
ar.forEach( function(element) {
    if( element['exhibition_id'] == 1 ){
        console.log(element);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhxwg2u5/

Am I missing something or was this everything?

Comment: great and a +1 for the jsFiddle link